# How to read\write settings from a Visual Studio Project file using NuGet?

Tags: nuget, read-write, visual-studio-project, nuget-package

I'm interested in creating a NuGet package for a documentation tool I'm writing. Ideally, I'd like the user to not have to configure my tool in anyway. In order to do this, I need to be able to read some settings from the Project's `.csproj` or `.vbproj` file to get the path of the Xml documentation file generated by the compiler. I also need to add a post-build step to the project.

I've looked through their documentation but I haven't seen any mention of being able to do this. Is this possible? If so, is there any documentation or examples of this available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using PowerShell script, you can access the rich `VS DTE` object model.  This allows your package to do all kind of things that NuGet doesn't have specific features for.  Look at this **[help topic](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package)** for some info on using `init.ps1` or `install.ps1`.